# 1200px grid with two columns

Tags: css

I am download an 1200px grid css from here: http://1200px.com/

I thought, it is really simple to just create a two column page layout.

So let's say:

```
<div class="container_15">
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="grid_7">
            test
        </div>
        <div class="grid_7">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and it's not good, there are space after second div.

Tried to play with push, etc... no success.

I've downloded the PSD and I saw, there are 15 columns. I am wondering, how can I create a two / three / four columned layout?

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: 15 columns? Thar seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: I'm afraid, you'll need to modify css by youself or generate a new one with tools from that website, cause currently it is not supposed to give you desired two column with exactly equal width. All you can use now is, as in your example, grid_7 + drid_7, or grid_7 + drid_8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not had direct experience with this grid system but you could always change the settings on the site and download a new version of the css file. 12 columns is a good number as you can easily create the 2, 3 & 4 column layouts.

[image: Example of settings on 1200px site]

Comment: Which seems like the best option except perhaps 16?

Comment: I tried it, the only problem is the site is down. Ok, this was my first thought too, just I thought, the problem is with me, and there is an option to earn this somehow, but no. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You are specifying a 15 column grid (.container_15) and then using two columns that only add up to 14 columns.

So of course you are going to have a gap after the second column - a one column gap....

Comment: Why the downvote here? I simply pointed out that two columns of 7 do not fit into 15, hence the gap OP is seeing!

What am i missing for this to be down voted?